# Snort Rules Data Structure

Tags: ids, snort

the IDS programm `Snort` uses a linked list to organize rules (ORT/OTN). This list is used in run time. How it is possible to view this data structure in run time?

Any tip would be helpful. Thanks in regards.

Jamada